# How to use \ with the read command?

Tags: linux, shell, rclone

I am a complete beginner in this topic and I usually search for a solution rather than just asking a question because I am sure that somebody had a similar problem. But this time I couldn't find a way to solve my problem. 
So I wrote a little shell script that uses rclone to copy files from a variable folder into my Google Drive. 
My problem is that I can't enter the folder name if it contains more than one word. I already tried using `read -r folder` but it returns

```
Command copy needs 2 arguments maximum: you provided 3 non flag arguments: ["One" "Folder/" "Drive:SomeFolder/File"]
```

and if I use `\` it returns

```
Command copy needs 2 arguments maximum: you provided 3 non flag arguments: ["One\\" "Folder/" "Drive:SomeFolder/File"]
```

I want the final command to look like this

```
rclone copy One\Folder/ Drive:SomeFolder/File
```

```
#!bin/sh
#upload

echo "Folder Name:"
read -r folder
echo "File Name:"
read -r name
rclone copy ${folder}/ Drive:SomeFolder/${name}
```

Comment: `help read` (in newer `bash`es), will show you `-r` for `raw` ; "do not allow backslashes to escape any characters". I'm not certain that's what you're looking for, so check out the other options listed. Good luck.

Comment: The problem is the way you invoke `rclone`, not the way you read the variables. You need to quote variable expansions. [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) automatically detects this and other common problems.

Comment: @thatotherguy Thank you so much! I will print this website on a piece of paper and put it on my wall.

Comment: Btw how do I set this question as answered?

Comment: Most editors also have plugins for this tool so that you can get the same suggestions while you write the script.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is the way you invoke rclone, not the way you read the
> variables. You need to quote variable expansions. ShellCheck
> automatically detects this and other common problems. – that other guy

Comment: need to wait 2 days...